# Gitlab Runner with shell executer is very slower than native

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use a mac mini as a GitLab runner; for this, I use the shell as executor,
the issue is if I try to build my app with GitLab runner, it becomes very slow, but I can build the same app on the same machine much faster (I get a timeout after +4 hours when I try to build with GitLab runner, but I can build the app in less than an hour native in the same machine)

I don't have any specific config for my GitLab runner all default.

I'm using GitLab  14.6.7-ee.

I wonder if there is some recourse limitation when we use GitLab runner, something like max memory
could anyone help here